# Where Is Vodianoi Found?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

This is one of my last monsters I need for the beastiary fragment. I know they are found in the Archyltte Steppe, but what weather? Or are they simply a rare spawn?

It seems like they should be spawning in stormy weather with the rest of the C'ieth, but after thirty minutes of searching the whole map I haven't found one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The monster is found near the sealed gate during cloudy weather.
I believe the area is called Grave Ridge

Comment: When you say cloudy do you mean stormy? What would the position of the controls be?

Comment: no i mean cloudy. Position of the controls would be up for both levers. Same conditions as those for Immortal

Comment: He is correct about how to find the Vodianoi and correct about the actual "weather type". However, in-game it is actually stormy looking, while they say it is cloudy weather and vise-versa. So I know what you mean ;P